# subplots for a combination of cell arrays

Tags: matlab, plot, cell-array

I am attempting to generate a figure with several subplots, e.g.

```
time = 1:365;
data = {rand(365,1),rand(365,1),rand(365,1)};
data2 = {rand(365,1),rand(365,1),rand(365,1)};

figure(1);
for i = 1:length(data);
    for ii = 1:2:2*length(data);
        for jj = 2:2:2*length(data);
            subplot(5,2,ii);
            plot(time,data{i});

            subplot(5,2,jj);
            plot(time,data2{i});
        end
    end
end
```

From this code I was trying to generate a subplot for each cell in 'data' and 'data2' where each of the cells in 'data' were plotted in subplots 1,3,5 and those in 'data2' in subplots 2,4,6. The code that I generate reproduces the same figure in all of the subplots for data and data2 instead of what I described above. I'm guessing the problem here is that the number of cells in each data set is 3 and the loop runs over 6 iterations? How can i fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. You don't need this nested loop there...

```
figure(1);
for i = 1:length(data);
    subplot(5,2,(i-1)*2+1);
    plot(time,data{i});

    subplot(5,2,(i-1)*2+2);
    plot(time,data2{i});
end
```